# deleting a row in legacy SQL

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

```
SELECT * FROM [dataset.HistoricalDashboard] 
OMIT RECORD IF IncidentNumber = 'INC0887'
```

I want to delete a row with that Incident number. Does this query deletes the row? Legacy SQL does not have delete function. so trying to figure it out

Comment: What's the specific legacy system, database, and/or operating system?

Comment: Is this regarding `BigQuery`?

Comment: @Ayesha . . . Use standard SQL.

Comment: I cant use standard, I have to use legacy only. yes its regarding big query

Comment: Why can't you use standard SQL? Note that you can put `#standardSQL` at the start of the query to force the mode.

Comment: DELETE FROM [dataset.HistoricalDashboard] 
WHERE  IncidentNumber = 'INC0887'...doesn't work?

Comment: delete command does not work in legacy sql. I tried to force it in standard, it is also also not working. any other suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

OMIT RECORD does not delete the row from the table. Instead, it populates whole results except for the records which are satisfying the given condition. You can use the query(given in question) and store results in another table.
For more information, please refer to the google doc:
https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/legacy-sql#omit